# Remove time portion of DateTime index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I query a service through their API for daily data, they throw in a time portion which is equal to whatever time the query was made. So my pandas dataframe looks like this when I called the function at 14:54:36 -

```
2018-05-16 14:54:36  1024.75  1008.25      ...        39221        242897
2018-05-17 14:54:36  1017.00  1002.00      ...        35361        241132
2018-05-18 14:54:36  1015.75  1002.75      ...        49090        242938
2018-05-21 14:54:36  1034.50  1020.75      ...        56950        243316
2018-05-22 14:54:36  1043.75  1028.50      ...        49724        247874
2018-05-23 14:54:36  1049.00  1036.25      ...        46256        253609
2018-05-24 14:54:36  1059.75  1047.00      ...        65352        259617
```

As this is daily data, the time portion is useless. When I do:

```
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=0, header=None,names=['High','Low','Open','Close','Volume','OpenInterest'])
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index,format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

The format doesn't seem to work. The DateTime index still contains time. Any idea how I can remove the time portion?

Comment: `df.index = df.index.values.astype('M8[D]')` ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can  maintain the datetime functionality and set the time portion to 00:00:00 with [`normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html).

```
df.index = df.index.normalize()

# For non-Index datetime64[ns] dtype columns you use the `.dt` accessor:
# df['column'] = df['column'].dt.normalize()
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4], index=pd.date_range('2018', periods=4, freq='H'))

df.index = df.index.normalize()

print(df)
#            0
#2018-01-01  1
#2018-01-01  2
#2018-01-01  3
#2018-01-01  4
```

Looking at the index:

```
df.index
#DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

And the values are Timestamps:

```
df.index[0]
#Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 29):

With the `date` attribute:

```
df.index = df.index.date
```

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4], index=pd.date_range('2018', periods=4, freq='H'))
>>> df.index = df.index.date
>>> df
            0
2018-01-01  1
2018-01-01  2
2018-01-01  3
2018-01-01  4
```

**Note**: that this will get you `object` dtype in Pandas.  All attributes are [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html).  It's technically an array of native Python `datetime.date` objects.  See ALollz's answer to keep the dtype datetime-like.

Comment: Yes--as I mentioned in the answer @ALollz.  Although, technically it is a NumPy array of python datetime.date objects.

Comment: I would say in all fairness to prefer @ALollz's answer if you want to work with the data as a time series.  This answer above is really about formatting, as is `df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, which you seemed to be getting at in the question.

Comment: I second @BradSolomon. Using `df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` is a great way of getting any format you like for the date objects.

Comment: an additional benefit is that in this way the timezone (+4,-1 etc) is removed

Comment: It drastically increases the memory footprint: `df.memory_usage(deep=True, index=True).sum()`

Answer (score 1):

## You can control your Index object with a simple function like this:

```
def set_date_range(start_date, number_of_periods, frequency):
            date_range = pd.date_range(start= start_date, periods=number_of_periods, freq=frequency)

            for date in date_range:
                print(date)
            print()

set_date_range('1/1/2018', 5, "MS")
```

## See the line below with the comment, it'll remove the time portion

```
def set_date_range(start_date, number_of_periods, frequency):
            date_range = pd.date_range(start= start_date, periods=number_of_periods, freq=frequency)

            date_range = date_range.date # ASSIGNING THIS GETS RID OF THE TIME PORTION

            for date in date_range:
                print(date)
            print()

set_date_range('1/1/2018', 5, "MS")
```