# Is there a way to return only dates (without time) when using tweepy/twitter API

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to do a frequency analysis of tweets based on keywords. I want to use the date as the x-axis, but the created_at function returns date & time. I was going to try to use split, but the index appears as (datetime.datetime(x,x,x,x,x,x,x)), which I can't figure out how to work with.

My code is as follows:

```
import os
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

consumer_key = "xxx"
consumer_secret = "xxx"
access_token = "xxx"
access_token_secret = "xxx"
##set values for keys

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
##authenticate keys/set access tokens?

api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    
search_words = "apple cider -filter:retweets"
date_since = "2020-07-01"
##set search words and search date limit

tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
              q=search_words,
              lang="en",
              since=date_since).items(5000)
                #finds tweets. can filter our retweets if wanted
                #,until="2020-07-08"

all_tweets = [[tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.user.location, tweet.created_at, tweet.text] for tweet in tweets]

#generates list containing username and location


tweet_text = pd.DataFrame(data=all_tweets, 
                    columns=['user', 'location','date', 'text'])
```

Comment: If it's a `DatetimeIndex` then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845338/remove-time-portion-of-datetime-index-in-pandas

Comment: The options do not seem to be working for me.