# How to show time of data downloaded by mplfinance (index type datetime)

Tags: python, datetime, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt

data = web.DataReader('AMZN', 'yahoo', dt.datetime(2021, 5, 3), dt.datetime(2021, 5, 5))
# read stock price of AMZN from Yahoo finance from 5/3/2021 to 5/5/2021

print(data)
print(data.index)
print(data.index[0])
```

Output:
[image]

The interesting thing is that the index column does not show time (its type is datetime), see the first print. But if I try to see an individual row, it does include the time (00:00:00, see the 3rd print). How can I include this time to the index while still keeping the type to be datatime? I don't understand why the time is not included in the index column.

In addition to curiosity, the second reason I try to do this is that I want to see the download time of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a couple corrections:

1. Although you may be visualizing your financial data with mplfinance, you are downloading it with Pandas DataReader.
2. Your question is really a question about the Pandas DatetimeIndex class (which mplfinance requires as the index to the dataframe you want to plot).
3. The type in a DatetimeIndex is not `datetime.datetime`, but rather `numpy.datetime64`.  That said, if you try to extract it as `data.index[0]` then pandas will return type `pandas.Timestamp`.  ([See also here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiXQd.png)).

To answer your question: **What you are seeing is a feature of Pandas DatetimeIndex**:  If it detects that the time portion of all of the Timestamps in a DatetimeIndex are all 00:00:00, then to save space and avoid confusion it will automatically *not* print the time portion.  (See also [**this question and its answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845338/remove-time-portion-of-datetime-index-in-pandas) where someone asked how to *remove* the time portion.)

Regarding Pandas DataReader, the download time is not going to be included in the dataframe, and since you are requesting daily data (*not* intraday data) each row corresponds to a specific date, referring to the entire trading day (Open,High,Low,Close) on that date, not referring to a specific time, therefore the data is not going to contain times (or will contain 00:00:00) for the various dates.

HTH.

P.S.  I'm not sure if you can get intraday data from 'yahoo' using pandas datareader.  Maybe; I don't know.  But I believe you *can* get intraday data using [**Alpha Vantage**](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#alpha-vantage) by specifying **`"av-intraday"`** in the call.

P.P.S.  I don't understand why you want to know what time you actually downloaded the data.  That said, you can get the current time when you do the download, and store that somewhere, for example:

```py
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt
data = web.DataReader(...)
download_time = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%D %H:%M:%S")
print(download_time)
```

`05/23/21 11:05:02`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! First, the reason I need to see the download time is that I want to plot the charts in a small period, say, every 10 second. I am thinking to write a code to control the download time and use *datetime.datetime.now()* to show the download time.  Second, I am just curious what if I want to enforce it to show the time 00:00:00? Here I still want the type to be datetime64 instead of string, as I need to plot later.

Comment: You can convert the time to any datetime-type that you want.  It really does sound like you want intraday data (every 10 seconds).  You should not be asking for daily data repeatedly, every10 seconds, and just time stamping it to now.

Comment: "You should not be asking for daily data repeatedly, every10 seconds, and just time stamping it to now."  -- To confirm that I understand your point correctly, you mean i just repeatedly request for the data without manually insert the 10 second "break time"? I am using [yfinance](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/ )  to download data, and the smallest time interval is 1min, and hence I want to code the 10 sec download interval by myself. Is there a simpler way? Thank!

Comment: What I am saying is, in the example in your question, you are asking for 3 days of **daily** data (*not intraday*) so you will always get 3 rows, whether you ask once, or ask every 10 seconds you will always get the same data, so there is no point to asking every 10 seconds.  If you use `yfinance` with `interval='1m'` then you will get new data only once per minute, so again no point in calling `yf.download()` every 10 seconds.

Comment: I see. Thank you! For the 3 days of daily data, the first two days will of course be the same. But the last day (assuming it's during the trading time) will be the newest data at "Close" price, and that's why I can request every 10 seconds to get the close prices. Btw, is there a way I can get the complete intraday data at an interval smaller than 1 min (for example, per 10 second)? For my method, I can only get the close price without open, high, low, and hence I cannot plot the candlestick chart for this interval (say, a candlestick for every 10 seconds).

Comment: The are many ways to get more frequent data, but I would guess at that frequency you may have to pay for it.   Also, if you are making trade decisions per data more frequent than a few minutes, you may also want to see bid/ask price *and* size.  And yes, you will most likely only get trade price, and/or bid/ask price (and sizes) so you will have to choose an interval and build your own OHLC sets (for example see "[Single time-series valuye to OHLC data](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Resampling-Time-Series-Data-with-Pandas#1-single-time-series-value-to-ohlc-data)")